# Querying and adding rows

Tags: sql, oracle11gr2

OK, this is a second attempt to resolve my issue, for those who will read this a second time, i hope its clear enough to understand a problem.

I am developing a query for a report, the thing is that while retrieving data from database this report should populate some rows, which do not exist. For illustrating purpose lets say i have these tables :

```
Table 1 - Companies

Table 2 - Transactions.

Table 3 - Transaction types.
```

Important detail that most of the companies do not have transactions of all transaction types. Although the report logic requires to dysplay a company with all of them : "real" ones with real money values and other, not existed ones with just $0. The problem starts here because transaction types are combined in logical groups, so lets say if a company has only 1 real transaction of type_1, the report should contain "$0" records of other types associated with type_1, like type_2, type_3 and type_4. If company has transactions of type_1 and type_2, report should be populated with some other tran types from different transaction type group etc.

The problem here is that the environment where it should be executed must be a pure sql (being a java programmer i understand how easy is to query database, load data into array[][] and add missing transaction types) - but the query should be ran on UNIX inside plsql batch so it should be single (or joined) select.

Thanks in advance. Any help or ideas would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just need some sort of outer join.  I'm guessing at how your tables relate to each other but it appears that you want something like

```
SELECT c_typ_cross_join.company_name, 
       c_typ_cross_join.transaction_type, 
       nvl( sum( t.transaction_amount ), 0 ) total_amt
  FROM (SELECT c.company_name,
               typ.transaction_type
          FROM companies c
               FULL OUTER JOIN transaction_type typ) c_typ_cross_join
       LEFT OUTER JOIN transactions t ON (    c_typ_cross_join.company_id       = t.company_id
                                          AND c_typ_cross_join.transaction_type = t.transaction_typ)
 GROUP BY c_typ_cross_join.company_name, 
          c_typ_cross_join.transaction_type
```

This should produce one row for every company for every transaction type and the sum of the related transactions (or 0 if there are no transactions for the combination of companies and transaction types).

Comment: Guys, thnk you very much, but i really did not mention anywhere there should be totals, it should be just all list of transactions.

Comment: @user1324100 - As Frank pointed out when you asked this question on OTN https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2373681&tstart=0 it would be very helpful to post table structures, some sample data, and the expected output.  So you want all the real transactions plus one fake transaction for any combination of `company_name` and `transaction_type` that has no real transactions?

Answer (score 0):

You could use two sub-queries one to find all transactions per company based on the existing types the company has, second to find the totals.

```
SELECT companies.id, all_transactions.transaction, COALESCE(sums.total_amount, 0)
FROM companies
JOIN (SELECT ct.companyid, t.transaction
    FROM transactions ct
    JOIN transactions t ON t.transactiontype = ct.transactiontype
    GROUP BY ct.companyid, t.transaction) all_transactions ON all_transactions.companyid = companies.companyid
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ct.companyid, SUM(t.amount) as total_amount
    FROM transactions ct
    GROUP BY ct.companyid) sums ON sums.companyid = companies.companyid
```